# Understanding Passing by value in Golang

Tags: function, go

While learning Golang, I was trying something out. I created 2 types (one struct and one string). Where I wanted to update values with a receiver function. The code is as follows:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type contactInfo struct {
    email   string
    zipCode int
}

type person struct {
    firstName string
    lastName  string
    age       int
    contact   contactInfo
}

type names []string

func main() {
    alex := person{"Alex", "Anderson", 30, contactInfo{"alex@mail.com", 12345}}
    namelist := names{}
    namelist = append(namelist, "Alex")
    namelist.updateNameList("Hello")
    fmt.Println(namelist)
    alex.updateName("Alexis")
    alex.print()
}

func (p person) print() {
    fmt.Printf("%s %s is %d years old and has email %s and zipcode %d\n", p.firstName, p.lastName, p.age, p.contact.email, p.contact.zipCode)
}

func (p person) updateName(newName string) {
    p.firstName = newName
}

func (n names) updateNameList(s string) {
    n[0] = s
}
```

Whose output came as:

```
➜ go run main.go
[Hello]
Alex Anderson is 30 years old and has email alex@mail.com and zipcode 12345
```

Now I am confused that, when I passed the struct to update the firstName value, it did not get updated. But when I passed the nameList, the original list got manipulated when passed to the function.
I know Go is a pass by value, and not by reference. But why did one get updated and not the other?

Comment: The function `updateName` modifies a field in receiver `p`. The variable `p` is discarded on return from the function. The function `updateNameList` modifies the backing array of receiver `n`.  The variable `n` shares the backing array with the caller's variable `nameList`.   See [Intro to Slices](https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro) for information on how slices work.

Comment: That's a classic problem for newcomers: slices are passed by value—just as everything else in Go. But slices contain a pointer to the underlying array, and it's that pointer which is copied when a slice value is passed around. When you update an element of a slice, you update an element in that backing array, which is accessed via the pointer contained in the slice.

Comment: Issue Resolved. The above link and these comments explained it.